# Mapping Common Properties only once for the whole Model in Entity Framework 7

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In my domain model I'm trying to setup mappings for common properties only for entities that are subclass of ***EntityBase***. For this purpose I'm trying to filter out using ***IsAssignableFrom*** but it is giving no results and not mapping happens for those properties.

Any advice on how to resolve the IsAssignableFrom issue, or any other way to verify entity hierarchy will be appreciated.

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
                {
                    var types = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().Where( entity =>   
            typeof(Domain.Core.Entity).IsAssignableFrom(entity.GetType()));
            foreach (var entType in types)
                    {                 
                         entType.AddProperty("CreatedBy", typeof (string));
                         entType.AddProperty("ModifiedBy", typeof(string));
                         entType.AddProperty("CreatedOn", typeof(DateTime));
                         entType.AddProperty("LastModifiedOn", typeof(DateTime));
                         entType.AddProperty("RowVersion", typeof(byte[]));
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Have you considered an interface that adds these properties instead?

Comment: @Eris the same way is no resolving for interface. Also this are Shadow properties, so they actually do not exist in my model at all.

Comment: Use `entity.ClrType`.

Comment: @GertArnold, concise and effective comment. GetEntityTypes returns IMutableEntityType objecs which is EF metadata and ClrType property provides me my real object type. If you post as an answer I'll mark it as the accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think [IsAssignableFrom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof(v=vs.110).aspx) is not used correctly in your case:

```
typeof(Domain.Core.EntityBase).IsAssignableFrom(entity.GetType())
```

should be used if your intention is to iterate through all types that derive (directly on indirectly) from EntityBase

Comment: Thanks for spotting this wrong usage of the method. I have tested it this way but unfortunately it does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Your on the right track, but I'd recommend that you should get your entity types using pure reflection rather than through the model. Try something like this:

```
        var asm = Assembly.Load("Domain.Core");
        foreach(var type in asm.GetTypes())
        {
            if(typeof(Domain.Core.Entity).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            {
                var builder = modelBuilder.Entity(type);
                builder.Property(typeof(string), "CreatedBy");
                // ...
            }
        }
```